# 'ServiceModel' does not exist in namespace 'System'. When I try to add a reference, it says it's already referenced

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-3.5, visual-studio-2013

I'm using Visual Studio Professional 2013, and I'm trying to import an ASP.NET web site whose files were on SVN so that I can run and debug the website locally. I created a new web site and changed the target framework to .NET 3.5 (that's what the guys who built the website told me it was in). So, I copied over the files to the website directory, and added them into the solution using "add->existing web site".

I get this error specifically:

```
The type or namespace name 'ServiceModel' does not exist in the namespace 'System' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
```

So, I think to myself, I'll just add a reference to ServiceModel, no big deal. So, I right-click the project, go to add reference, look for System.ServiceModel under Assemblies->Framework, check it, and click ok. Then this happens:

```
The Web site is already referencing the assembly 'System.ServiceModel'.
```

These things might help:

- My target framework is not "Client Profile". That option isn't available to me in VS2013
- When I make a new web site project and just add a basic class file, I can use the System.ServiceModel namespace because it's already referenced.
- When I look in Class View at "Project References", I don't see System.ServiceModel. In the above "new website project", I DO see System.ServiceModel under Class View.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? I'm encountering a similar issue.

Answer (score 7):

Add a reference to the assembly System.ServiceModel. Select Project-> Add Reference and then select the assembly name.

Comment: I already had a reference to System.ServiceModel in my project -- I had to delete and re-add it.

Comment: I had to close VS and restart it

Answer (score 1):

Copy System.ServiceModel.dll from "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319" to project bin folder.

Comment: worked for me when I added to the the debug folder. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

- Delete Service Ref
- Unload project
- Delete `<RootNamespace>MyProject</RootNamespace>`
- Reload project
- Re-add Service Ref
- Build

Comment: That only changes the namespace used for new classes added to the project.